# Find named ranges within certain range

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to display the total # of named ranges on a sheet named Pricing Worksheet.

```
Sub countNamedRanges()
    
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim nameCount As Integer

    'loop through all names in the workbook
    For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    'Debug.Print Split(nm.RefersTo, "!")(0)
        If Split(nm.RefersTo, "!")(0) = "='Pricing Worksheet'" Then nameCount = nameCount + 1
    Next
    Debug.Print nameCount
End Sub
```

This works well but looks at all named ranges in that sheet.
I am wondering how to have it list named ranges only found within A1:AD190 of the Pricing Worksheet

Thanks

Comment: What if the named range spans from AC1:AE1, i.e. it's not completely within A1:AD190?

Answer (score 2):

Name objects have a `RefersToRange` object which contains the range itself where all the other `RefersTo*` properties return a string.

Because you get the actual range back you don't have to perform string splitting to test if it's in your workbook. You can also check to see if that range intersects with another range that you might be interested:

```
For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If nm.RefersToRange.Worksheet.Name = "Pricing Worksheet" Then
        If Not Intersect(nm.RefersToRange, Sheets("Pricing Worksheet").Range("A1:AD190")) Is Nothing Then
            nameCount = nameCount + 1
        End If
    End If
Next
```

That's just testing for intersection so if your named range refers to `A1:A10` this will count it. It will also count `AD1:AJ5000` as that will also intersect. You can adjust this code accordingly.